# How to install apache in ubuntu-16.04?

Tags: ubuntu-16.04

Earlier I had installed apache without issues. But after formatting my laptop, I am facing this problem.

According to the error messages I search the solution codes and go through those codes. But it is not working.

Comment: Please provide more info, what error messages?

Answer (score 2):

You can easily install Apache into your Ubuntu 16.04, by the following steps.

In ubuntu first, we need to update and upgrade by using the following commands

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

then you can install Apache2 by following the command

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

After the installation you can check in the browser.

```
http://your_server_ip
```

there you can see the apache2 page over there.

Comment: For more information, you can check the link
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-the-apache-web-server-on-ubuntu-18-04-quickstart

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get install apache2 -y
```

Comment: I enter this code.But It was not work.It give error messages.

Comment: What error messages? It's hard to help without knowing the problem.

Comment: Some index files failed to download, they have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Answer (score 1):

1. `sudo apt-get install libpcre3 libpcre3-dev libapr1 libapr1-dev libaprutil1 libaprutil1-dev`
2. `wget http://mirrors.fibergrid.in/apache//httpd/httpd-2.4.37.tar.gz`
3. `tar -xvzf httpd-2.4.37.tar.gz`
4. `cd httpd-2.4.37`
5. `./configure --prefix=/usr/local/apache`
6. `make`
7. `make install`

Apache will be installed at prefix given i.e. */usr/local/apache/*

Answer (score 0):

Install Apache In Ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install apache2
sudo ufw app list
sudo ufw allow 'Apache Full'
sudo ufw status // Status will be inactive.
sudo systemctl status apache2 // Apache server will be Active.
```

Check Apache Server
You can check your apache server is properly working or not via your IP.
Enter in your Browser

http://server_domain_or_IP

You will find the Default page.

Mange Apache Process

```
sudo systemctl stop apache2 // Stop Apache Server
sudo systemctl start apache2 // Start Apache Server
sudo systemctl restart apache2 // Restart Apache Server
sudo systemctl reload apache2 // Reload Apache Server
sudo systemctl disable apache2 // Disable Auto Start Server
sudo systemctl enable apache2 // Enable Auto Start Server
```

Answer (score 0):

1. sudo apt-get update
2. sudo apt-get install apache2
3. sudo vim /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
   AllowOverride all    (Change from none to all)
   Require all granted  (Change require all to granted)

   AccessFileName .htaccess

   Require all granted     (Change none to all)
4. sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/
5. sudo a2enmod rewrite
6. sudo systemctl restart apache2

Done..
check with your ip (localhost)
http://server_domain_or_IP